# Can´t send Emails with BookedScheduler

Tags: php, phpmailer

i have the following problem: 
There is a setup of BookedScheduler (https://www.bookedscheduler.com/) on a FreeBSD-server. Thing itself runs, but the EMail-notifications just don´t work and i don´t know what the hell i can do. I only get this bad boy here:[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPFpy.png)

I see that there is an authentication error, but i couldn´t find anything helpful to solve it.
The Mail server is from my university.

Mailer is smtp.
smtp-Port is 587.
smtp.secure is tls.

I know this isn´t very specific information, but I am completely clueless. I´ll try to answer all of your questions if I can.
Hope someone can help me.

Thanks in advance,
Konstantin

Comment: It's failing immediately after issuing STARTTLS, which suggests it's either missing the openssl PHP extension, or that your CA certificates are out of date. Read the troubleshooting guide that's linked from your error message for more info on both of these.

Comment: Openssl is installed. Do you mean that the Certificates of my program or the ones of the mailserver are out of date? Or both?

Comment: The CA certificates installed on your server - they are used to verify the certificates presented by the mail servers you connect to.